# Difference between Renderer and ElementRef in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, elementref, angular-renderer2, angular-renderer

What is the difference between `Renderer`  and `ElementRef`? In Angular both are used for DOM Manipulation. I am currently using `ElementRef` alone for writing Angular 2 directives. If I get more info about `Renderer`, I can use that in my future directives.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `Renderer` is a class that is a partial abstraction over the DOM.
Using the `Renderer` for manipulating the DOM doesn't break server-side rendering or Web Workers (where direct access to the DOM would break).

`ElementRef` is a class that can hold a reference to a DOM element.
This is again an abstraction to not break in environments where the browsers DOM isn't actually available.

If `ElementRef` is injected to a component, the injected instance is a reference to the host element of the current component.

There are other ways to acquire an `ElementRef` instance like `@ViewChild()`, `@ViewChildren()`, `@ContentChild()`, `@ContentChildren()`. In this case `ElementRef` is a reference to the matching element(s) in the template or children.

`Renderer` and `ElementRef` are not "either this or that", but instead they have to be used together to get full platform abstraction.

`Renderer` acts on the DOM and `ElementRef` is a reference to an element in the DOM the `Renderer` acts on.

Comment: I'm wondering why renderer methods require `elementRef.nativeElement` instead of working with `elementRef` like `viewContainerRef`. This seems to be a bit inconsistent. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks inconsistent, but I think it isn't. In earlier beta versions `renderer` just took `ElementRef` but they changed it later. I think in platforms like `Universal` `ElementRef.nativeElement` doesn't actually refer to a DOM element. If you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html you'll see that `nativeElement` is of type `any` instead of `HTMLElement`

Comment: _In earlier beta versions renderer just took ElementRef but they changed it later._ - that's interesting, thanks. yeah, `nativeElement` can refer to platform specific elements, but passing elementRef instead of elementRef.nativeElement is still a higher abstraction and would work any way

Comment: I don't remember seeing a reason mentioned why they changed it.

Comment: Just checked sources, existing renderer is depracated in the most recent versions.

Comment: I think I saw something like that mentioned. I don't know yet what the alternative approach will be.

Answer (score 6):

Do notice that you should refrain from using ElementHref as it flagged with a security risk.

**Angular 2 Documentation:**

"Permitting direct access to the DOM can make your application more vulnerable to XSS attacks. Carefully review any use of ElementRef in your code. For more detail, see the Security Guide."

"Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead. Alternatively you take a look at Renderer which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported."

Comment: Actually using `ElementRef` itself doesn't do any harm. The culprit is `ElementRef.nativeElement`. This is IMHO (I'm all but a security expert) only security relevant if user provided data is used to add to the DOM, right?