# Iterate HTML tags with angular 7? (dynamically)

Tags: angular, iteration, dynamic-html

The interesting thing is that it is a dynamic component that can iterate html attributes and style.

We know that `[ngStyle]` needs a json object with properties of type css.

I have not seen in angular an `[ngAtrributes]` that needs a json object with attributes.

The idea and goal is to create dynamic html elements to be able to render.

Thinking about a dynamic form is not a good idea because I would lack elements such as a div, img, etc.

I tried with this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481199/9420442
It's very good, but it has a missing one, how could I enter text inside the tags ?, for example: `<div> Hello world! </ Div>` how could I enter 'Hello world!' with this proposal?

The main one I want is this:

HTML:

```
<{{tag.tagName}} *ngFor="let tag in tags"
                 [ngStyle]="tag.style"
                 [ngAtrr]="tag.atrributes">
                 {{tag.text}}
</{{tag.tagName}}>
```

TS:

```
this.tags = [
    {
      tag: 'div',
      atrributes: [
        {'class': 'text-center'}
      ],
      'style': [
        {'back-ground-color': 'red'},
        {'color': 'blue'}
      ],
      'text': 'Hello World!'
    },
    {
      tag: 'input',
      type: 'number'
      atrributes: [
        {'max': '10'},
        {'place-holder': 'hello hello!'}
      ],
      'style': [
        {'back-ground-color': 'red'},
        {'color': 'blue'}
      ],
      'value': '100'
    }
];
```

This is what I expect.
Could you help me a little on how to achieve this functionality?

```
<div class="text-center">Hello World!</div>

<input type="number" placeHolder="hello world" max="10" value="100"></input>
```

Comment: Have you looked at building an attribute directive to handle this? https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#attribute-directives

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be written in this way

```
<div  *ngFor="let tag in tags">
  <{{tag.tagName}}
                 [ngStyle]="tag.style"
                 [ngAtrr]="tag.atrributes">
                 {{tag.text}}
  </{{tag.tagName}}>
</div>
```