# addEventListener on dynamically created elements not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to add click events to images present in inner html. But when I try to add it, it won't work.

Template

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>
```

Code

myHtml;

```
ngOnInit() {
    const root = document.createElement('div');
    root.innerHTML = this.getHtml();
    const images = root.getElementsByTagName('img');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (image: HTMLImageElement, i) => {
      image.addEventListener('click', (event: any) => {
        console.log('click', event);
      });
    });
    this.myHtml = root.innerHTML;
  }
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbqjcr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @Suhel Khan if you want to select and addEventListener all `<img>` you can check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **ngAfterViewInit()** to achieve this,
I have modified the code and is working fine.

Please check the link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7da7cd

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [`elementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) for specifying `<img>` element. Then you can use the following to add event listener into all `<img>`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('img');
    if (elem) {
      elem.forEach(res => {
        res.addEventListener('click', this.onclick.bind(this));
      })
    }
}
```

Note that:

```
onclick() {
    alert("Image clicked");
}
```

is a custom function which you can customize. And don't forget to `import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';`

[**Stackblitz Fork**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfr6od?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

More detail into [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit), [`.bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530386/3654837), the difference between [`ElementRef` and `Renderer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39785176/3654837)

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to restriction that event listener will be registered only for elements before page cycle starts. Did you try doing it more angular-ish way by Renderer2

```
this.renderer.listen('img', 'click', (evt) => {
  console.log('Clicking the document', evt);
});
```

Docs : https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: Thanks, this is also work, but instead of 'img' target good to send the nativeElement of the required element

Answer (score 1):

Its not yet in the DOM. Do the same with `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const root = document.createElement('div');
    root.innerHTML = this.getHtml();
    const images = root.getElementsByTagName('img');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, (image: HTMLImageElement, i) => {
      image.addEventListener('click', (event: any) => {
        console.log('click', event);
      });
    });
    this.myHtml = root.innerHTML;
  }
```