# Adding event handler for element from raw HTML

Tags: html, angular, element

The application gets raw HTML string from external API and I need to render this data. Also handler for `click` event of `span id="sp1"` should be added.

After reading the articles:

- [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding)
- [addEventListener on dynamically created elements not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302087/addeventlistener-on-dynamically-created-elements-not-working)

I am trying to do it with the [code below (StackBlitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/addingeventhandler?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  myHtml;

  logInfo() {
    console.log('TEST clicked!');
  }

  getApiData() {
    // In prod the rawHtml value retrivied by external call
    var rawHtml = `<h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2><span id="sp1">TEST</span>`;

    this.myHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(rawHtml);
    var elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#sp1');
    if (elem) {
      elem.addEventListener('click', this.logInfo.bind(this));
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>
<button (click)="getApiData()">Get API Data</button>
```

---

It does not work:

1. Click the "Get API Data" button.
2. Click the "TEST" label.
3. **"TEST clicked" text is not displayed in the console.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait until **DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml** updates the real DOM before searching the element, for example:

```
getApiData() {
  // In prod the rawHtml value retrieved by external call
  var rawHtml = `<h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2><span id="sp1">TEST</span>`;

  this.myHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(rawHtml);
  setTimeout(() => {
    var elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#sp1');
    if (elem) {
      elem.addEventListener('click', this.logInfo.bind(this));
    }
  }, 0)
}
```