# Angular code does not run after "getElementByID"

Tags: angular

Here is my Angular function.

```
getUserdata(){
    console.log("Test")//This is Working
    const getHtmlContent = document.getElementById('getContent') as HTMLElement;
    const getTextContent = getHtmlContent.innerText;
    console.log("Test");//This is not working
    console.log(getTextContent);//This is not working
}
```

Comment: `getHtmlContent3` isn't defined. *post edit* can you provide your HTML or a reproducible example

Comment: are there any errors in the console? if `#getContent` isn't found in DOM, you should see `cannot read property innerText of null` or something.

Comment: If you are using angular why are you using `getElementById`?

Answer (score 0):

There's two options here, one is to implement the `OnInit` interface, the other is to use template tagging and `AfterViewInit`:

```
<p id="para" #para></p>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('para') paraEl: ElementRef

  ngOnInit() {
    const p = document.getElementById('para')
    console.log('ngInit', p.innerText)
  } 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ViewChild', this.paraEl.nativeElement.innerText)
  }
}
```

I would recommend the `AfterViewInit` solution.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwdovy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: paraEl will be available after **ngAfterViewInit**. User **render2** to interact with the dom.

Comment: Agreed if there's DOM interaction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785118/difference-between-renderer-and-elementref-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Following has an interaction example as well.

**HTML**

```
<p #interestedElement>
  Initial Content
</p>
<button (click)="changeContent()">Press To Change Content</button>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from 
         '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('interestedElement') element: ElementRef

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ViewChild', this.element.nativeElement.innerText)
  }

  changeContent() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.element.nativeElement, 'innerText', 'Changed Text')

    // Yes you can do the following as well but the recommended method is above
    // this.element.nativeElement.innerText =  'Changed Text'
  }
}
```

**Example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-flthju

**Some Renderer2 related documentation**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-using-renderer2